# call function through function to search array

Tags: php, arrays, function, search, multidimensional-array

My objective is to search a multidimentional array for a plot and output information about who is buried there.

My code is

```
function searchByPlot($plot, $array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
      if ($val['plot'] === $plot) {
          return $key;
      }
  }
  return null;
}



function calculate() {
    $id = searchByPlot('681', $ma);
    $code = $ma[$id]['code'];
    $last = $ma[$id]['h_last'];
    $plot = $ma[$id]['plot'];

  if (isset($last)){
    echo 'ID: '.$id.' Code: '.$code.' Lastname'.$last.'';
  }

  echo "Test".$id."";
}


calculate();
```

However when i call the calculate function there is no response even though there is a result in the array.

When i call the searchByPlot function directly it works fine.

```
$id = searchByPlot('681', $ma);
echo $id;
```

However when i call the calculate function it doesn't work at all, nothing is outputted on $id as you can see my test call above.

```
echo $id;
```

Can you help please?

Many thanks, Buster

Comment: Consider posting complete code please.

Comment: I dont see `$ma` is declared in the `calculate()` function